# Freeradius 3 not saving accounting records to Mysql

Tags: freeradius, accounting

Freeradius is not saving account data to MySQL database, can you please advise
config

```
accounting {
### detail
  #  See "Accounting queries" in mods-available/sql
  sql
  #  Filter attributes from the accounting response.
#   attr_filter.accounting_response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debian

Enable sql in the following files by removing the preceding "-" i.e change "-sql" to "sql"

1. `/etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-available/default`
2. `/etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-available/inner-tunnel`

Restart FreeRadius service

```
systemctl restart freeradius
```

You may get this error:

> ERROR: (9) sql: ERROR: rlm_sql_mysql: ERROR 1054 (Unknown column
> 'acctupdatetime' in 'field list')

To solve it follow these steps >> https://serverfault.com/questions/1095415/daloradius-error-3-sql-error-rlm-sql-mysql-error-1054-unknown-column-acc